# Flutter TextField ScrollBar bottom margin

Tags: flutter

When I insert a multi-line TextField inside the ScrollBar, then add a lot of lines, then scroll it to the end, the rewind line on the right side does not reach the end. Why?

[image: Flutter EditField and ScrollBar]

```
Widget _buildTextField() {
controller = TextEditingController(
  text: text,
);
controller.addListener(_onTextChanged);
return Scrollbar(
  child: TextField(
    style: Styles.headlineRegular(color: ThemeColors.blackText),
    controller: controller,
    maxLines: widget.maxLines,
    minLines: widget.minLines,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      fillColor: ThemeColors.veryLightGray,
      filled: true,
      hintStyle: Styles.headlineRegular(color: ThemeColors.darkGray),
      hintText: widget.hintText,
      enabledBorder: _buildBorder(ThemeColors.lightGray),
      focusedBorder: _buildBorder(ThemeColors.darkGray),
    ),
  ),
);}
```

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: I have same issue, but I couldn't handle it. so, I said that I can't style a textfield scrollbar to my team designer.

Answer (score 1):

Add `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero` inside the IntputDecoration, it will remove that scrollbar padding.
Then you can wrap everything in a Padding Widget without messing the scrollbar.

```dart
Widget _buildTextField() {
    controller = TextEditingController(
        text: text,
    );
    controller.addListener(_onTextChanged);

    return Scrollbar(
        child: TextField(
            style: Styles.headlineRegular(color: ThemeColors.blackText),
            controller: controller,
            maxLines: widget.maxLines,
            minLines: widget.minLines,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, // <----- ADD THIS LINE
                fillColor: ThemeColors.veryLightGray,
                filled: true,
                hintStyle: Styles.headlineRegular(color: ThemeColors.darkGray),
                hintText: widget.hintText,
                enabledBorder: _buildBorder(ThemeColors.lightGray),
                focusedBorder: _buildBorder(ThemeColors.darkGray),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: This does it, but only to add something: You can set top, right and left padding. The problem is only the bottom padding.